# OpenSSL Command Line and Ruby OpenSSL library differ when using same parameters to encrypt text

Tags: ruby, encryption, cryptography, openssl, encryption-symmetric

Note:  Using OpenSSL for symmetric encryption of text.

I made a Ruby script to test OpenSSL and I found I'm getting different results.  The key, iv, and ciphers are identical, so I would expect the results to be identical.  But they are not.  Here's my script:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

key = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
iv = "00000000000000000000000000000000"

### OPENSSL Command Line ###
puts "*** OpenSSL Command Line ***"
print "Encrypted via Command Line:  "
string = `printf %s \"Hello\" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K #{key} -iv #{iv} -base64`

puts string
puts string.inspect

print "Decrypted Data is:  "
puts `printf %s \"BC2+AQJ6ZQx0al3GXba+EQ==\n\" | openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -K #{key} -  iv #{iv} -base64`
puts "\n"

### Ruby OpenSSL Library ###
puts "*** OpenSSL Ruby Library ***"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-cbc').encrypt
cipher.padding = 1
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv

encrypted_data = cipher.update("Hello")
encrypted_data << cipher.final
encrypted_data = Base64.encode64(encrypted_data)
puts "Encrypted via Ruby is: #{encrypted_data}"
puts encrypted_data.inspect

decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-cbc').decrypt
decipher.key = key
decipher.iv = iv

data = decipher.update(Base64.decode64(encrypted_data))
data << decipher.final
puts "Decrypted Data:  #{data}"
```

The results are:

```
*** OpenSSL Command Line ***
Encrypted via Command Line:  BC2+AQJ6ZQx0al3GXba+EQ==
"BC2+AQJ6ZQx0al3GXba+EQ==\n"
Decrypted Data is:  Hello

*** OpenSSL Ruby Library ***
Encrypted via Ruby is: ZkeNEgsUXi1J7ps6kCQxdQ==
"ZkeNEgsUXi1J7ps6kCQxdQ==\n"
Decrypted Data:  Hello
```

Just a curious result.  Any idea what's causing the data to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, without knowing Ruby's OpenSSL interface:

You give the keys and initialization vector to the command line OpenSSL in hexadecimal encoding. E.g. your key and initialization vector are `0x000...`.

I suppose your Ruby library takes the key and initialization vector as binary data, e.g you are actually passing a key and initialization vector consisting of `0x30303030...` (assuming ASCII or anything compatible to it) instead of `0x00000...`.

Comment: You do not specify padding for the SSL Command Line.  It is possible that the default padding is different, hence a different encrypted block.

Answer (score 0):

Pack them  to a binary(Hex) sequence will fix it.
 Test on my machine(Mac ox 10.11.1 ruby-2.2.3).

```
cipher.key = ["#{key}"].pack('H*')
cipher.iv = ["#{iv}"].pack('H*')
```

[ruby Packs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/pack)

```
decipher.key = ["#{key}"].pack('H*')
decipher.iv = ["#{iv}"].pack('H*')
```